# Script wont display the total prices

Tags: javascript, html, json

Im new to coding. Can anyone see why my script wont display the total prices of the different providers when I click calculate button? (I have two json files for data consumption.json and providers.json) I only want someone to look over and look for any mistakes I can have made.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Energy Consumption Calculator</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Energy Consumption Calculator</h1>
    <form id="calculation-form">
        <div>
          <label for="fixedPrice">Fixed Price:</label>
          <input type="number" id="fixedPrice" name="fixedPrice">
        </div>
        <div>
          <label for="variablePrice">Variable Price:</label>
          <input type="number" id="variablePrice" name="variablePrice">
        </div>
        <div>
          <label for="spotPrice">Spot Price:</label>
          <input type="number" id="spotPrice" name="spotPrice">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" onclick="calculatePrice()">Calculate</button>
      </form>
      <div id="output"></div>

    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
async function getData(url) {
    const response = await fetch(url);
    console.log(response);
    return response.json();
}

async function calculatePrice() {
    const consumptionData = await getData("consumption.json");
    const providersData = await getData("providers.json");

    let prices = [];
    let fixedtotalPrice = 0;
    let variabletotalPrice = 0;
    let hourlytotalPrice = 0;
    let monthlytotalPrice = 0;
    for (const provider of providersData) {
        for (const consumption of consumptionData) {
            if (provider.pricingModel === "fixed") {
                // Get the fixedPrice value from user input
                const fixedPrice = parseFloat(document.getElementById("fixedPrice").value);
                fixedtotalPrice += fixedPrice * consumption.consumption;
            } else if (provider.pricingModel === "variable") {
                // Get the variablePrice value from user input
                const variablePrice = parseFloat(document.getElementById("variablePrice").value);
                variabletotalPrice += consumption.consumption * variablePrice;
            } else if (provider.pricingModel === "spotPrice") {
                // Get the spotPrice value from user input
                const spotPrice = parseFloat(document.getElementById("spotPrice").value);
                hourlytotalPrice += consumption.consumption * spotPrice;
            } else if (provider.pricingModel === "spotPrice") {
                // Get the spotPrice value from user input
                const spotPrice = parseFloat(document.getElementById("spotPrice").value);
                monthlytotalPrice += spotPrice * consumption.consumption;
            }
        }
    }

    prices.push({ provider: "Vest Energi", totalPrice: fixedtotalPrice });
    prices.push({ provider: "Øst Energi", totalPrice: variabletotalPrice });
    prices.push({ provider: "Nord Energi", totalPrice: hourlytotalPrice });
    prices.push({ provider: "Syd Energi", totalPrice: monthlytotalPrice });

    let output = "<ul>";
    for (const price of prices) {
        output += `<li>${price.provider}: ${price.totalPrice}</li>`;
    }
    output += "</ul>";
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = output;
}

const form = document.getElementById("calculation-form");
form.addEventListener("submit", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    calculatePrice();
});
```

Can't find the mistake.Dont think it has anything to with the json files, but something in my code.

Comment: you didnt include your script inside the html template

Comment: Yeah I just figured out! thanks